# Querying XML DOM Trees

Tags: xml, dom, xpath, xml-parsing, dom-traversal

i've got to solve the following problem. I have two XML, documents like the following

Example 1:

```
<page>
   <zone>
     <ln>
        <wd> texttext></wd>
        <wd> testestes></wd>
     <ln>
     <ln>
        <wd> texttext></wd>
        <wd> testestes></wd>
     <ln>
   </zone>
   <zone>
     <ln>
        <wd> textawgwagtext></wd>
        <wd> testawgwgestes></wd>
     <ln>
   </zone>
</page>
```

Example 2:

```
<page>
   <zone>
     <ln>
        <wd> tewahawhxttexawgawht></wd>
        <wd> testawhawtawawgawawgestes></wd>
     <ln>
   </zone>
   <zone>
     <ln>
        <wd> texttext></wd>
        <wd> testestes></wd>
     <ln>
     <ln>
        <wd> texttext></wd>
        <wd> testestes></wd>
     <ln>
     <ln>
        <wd> textawgwagtext></wd>
        <wd> testawgwgestes></wd>
     <ln>
   </zone>
</page>
```

Now i would like to compare those documents in a top down way. So for example i would like to compare the first zones of both docuemts, afterwards the first line block. So that in the end, i can compare the second word node, of the first line node, in the first zone of the first document is "testestes" and it's "testawhawtawawgawawgestes" in the second document. 
I've already parsed the documents with DOM, so I'd be glad to query them using DOM.
I'm very much looking foreward to your help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is non-trivial. Why do you want to compare? To show the difference or to be able to get from 1 to 2 (or vice versa)? Does the relative location of a node matter or not? There exists many algorithms for turning one tree into another (and thereby "specifying" the difference), but we need more "flesh" to help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not only looking for differences, also for similarities. So i want to know, what is the content of the third word node, of the second line node in the third zone and compare that to a node at the same position in an other document, or even better: to compare it to nodes at other positions. I need to match/compare nodes according to their position and content in different documents. Thanks again.